# Can not Reach to Array Element from Another View SwiftUI

Tags: data-binding, swiftui, observedobject

[GitHub Project Link](https://github.com/m3rtkoksal/MoovPayment)

I have a creditCard Model and CreditCards class that has a function to append creditCard.

```
class CreditCard: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
@Published var _id: String = UUID().uuidString
@Published var _cardOwnerName : String = ""
@Published var _cardNumber: String = ""
@Published var _cardExpMonth: String = ""
@Published var _cardExpYear: String = ""
@Published var _cardName: String = ""
@Published var _ccv: String = ""

@Published var items = [CreditCard]()

init(cardOwnerName: String, cardNumber: String, cardExpMonth: String,cardExpYear: String, cardName:String, ccv:String)
    {
        self._cardOwnerName = cardOwnerName
        self._cardNumber = cardNumber
        self._cardExpMonth = cardExpMonth
        self._cardExpYear = cardExpYear
        self._cardName = cardName
        self._ccv = ccv
    }
 }

class CreditCards: ObservableObject {
@Published var items = [CreditCard]()


func appendNewCreditCard(creditCard: CreditCard) {
    objectWillChange.send()
    items.append(CreditCard(cardOwnerName: creditCard._cardOwnerName, cardNumber: creditCard._cardNumber, cardExpMonth: creditCard._cardExpMonth, cardExpYear: creditCard._cardExpYear, cardName: creditCard._cardName, ccv: creditCard._ccv))
   }
}
```

I am appending a new credit card when all the conditions are met through a button.

```
struct CardInfo : View {
@State var creditCard : CreditCard
@ObservedObject var creditCards = CreditCards()

  CreditCardTextField(data: $cardNumberText, tFtext: "Kredi Kart Numarasi", tFImage: "credit")
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .onReceive(Just(cardNumberText)) { cardNumberdata in
                    if cardNumberdata.count == 16 {
                        self.creditCard._cardNumber = self.cardNumberText
                    }
            }

  Button(action: {
                    self.isSaved.toggle()
                    if self.creditCard._cardNumber == "" {
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    } else if self.creditCard._cardNumber.count == 16 {
                        self.successAlert = true
                        self.creditCards.objectWillChange.send()
                        self.creditCards.appendNewCreditCard(creditCard: creditCard)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                           self.successAlert = false    // hide popup
                           self.showAddressView = true    // eg. activate navigation link
                        }
                    }
                }
```

When I try to show text in my PaymentMethodView as below I cannot see any text on PaymentMethodView.

```
struct PaymentMethodView: View {
@ObservedObject var creditCards = CreditCardArray()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TopBarPM()
        MiddleView()
            .padding()
        DetailLine()
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image("credit")
                VStack {
                    ForEach(creditCards.items) { item in
                        Text(item._cardName)
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

}

Now I need to show those credit cards in another in PaymentMethodView

Comment: Are you calling one of the views from the other? Then you can just use a Binding and pass the credit card array as an argument. In case that they're completely separated you could use an EnvironmentObject which holds the credit card array and is accessible from all views

Comment: When I change State with Biinding for creditCards I am getting Cannot convert value of type '[CreditCard]' to specified type 'Binding<V>'

Comment: I see you updated your code but now the view where you're creating the credit cards is missing, therefore I don't think that I can come up with a appropriate solution to your problem.

Comment: I have added github project link to the question. You can see the whole project. @the.blaggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing. It seems that the `AddCreditCardView` and `PaymentMethodView` (where you're referencing a `CreditCardArray`) are two completely separated views which aren't calling each other. Therefore I would suggest to use the `CreditCardArray` as `EnvironmentObject`.

Currently you're creating in both views new `ObservedObject` `CreditCardArray`s, therefore you don't have any data to show in the `PaymentMethodView`.

When using an `EnvironmentObject` you can inject it into a view which holds `AddCreditCardView` and `PaymentMethodView`. Just choose the `SceneDelegate` for it and replace the line:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
```

with

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(CreditCardArray())
```

Here you're creating an object of `CreditCardArray` which you can access throughout the whole application.

You can access this object now by replacing the following line (in  `AddCreditCardView` and `PaymentMethodView`):

```
@ObservedObject var creditCards = CreditCardArray()
```

with

```
@EnvironmentObject var creditCards: CreditCardArray
```

in order to access the previously created array instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I add other arrays to contentView? I've tried as let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(CreditCards(), PersonalAddresses(), CorporateAddresses()) but does not compile as I thought it will.

Comment: I did it.   let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(CreditCards())
                                        .environmentObject(PersonalAddresses())
                                        .environmentObject(CorporateAddresses())